# How to extract "*" without providing the quotes while running the executable

Tags: c, bash, shell

```
[root@aman dir2]# ls
d1  d2  d3  d4  d5  f1  f2  f3  f4  f5
[root@aman dir2]# rm -f *
rm: cannot remove `d1': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove `d2': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove `d3': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove `d4': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove `d5': Is a directory
[root@aman dir2]# ls
d1  d2  d3  d4  d5
[root@aman dir2]# rm -rf *
[root@aman dir2]# ls
[root@aman dir2]#
```

I'm writing a tool to delete the files and directories present. I need to validate if the user has given argument as `"*"`, then to delete all the files and folders. But the `"*"` when given as arguments takes the no of files and folders present in the directory, how to validate the `"*"` without giving inside the double quotes.

`./a.out *` or `./a.out -f *` or `./a.out -rf *`. I cannot give as `./a.out "*"`. I need to input as `./a.out *` and do the validation. How to do this?

Comment: Wildcard expansion is done by the shell, by the time your program is running it's too late. Instead you could perform your own expansion of `*` and see if it matches what the commandline is (although this is not foolproof as the directory contents may change in the interim)

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely cannot do this.  The reason is that it's your shell, and not any part of your running process, which expands wildcards like `*`.  You have some options, though:

1. Make your program take a wildcard in quoted form, such as `'*'`, and expand it internally using `glob`, `fnmatch`, etc.  You can detect if a wildcard was already expanded by the shell by noticing that multiple input arguments arrived, or if a single one did, that it is an existing filename (`*` is unlikely to exist in real filenames).  This comes with the advantage that you will never fail to process very large expansions; the shell itself can't pass you more than a certain amount of characters on the command line which is a limitation in wildcarding sometimes.
2. Make your program refuse to operate on more than N files at once.  This might be a useful safeguard in some cases.
3. Patch the shell on your system to store the current, unexpanded command line in an environment variable, and read it from within your program.  This is only for the bold!